# How to print two lines of several files to a new file with speicific order?

Tags: awk

I have a task to do with `awk`. I am doing sequence analysis for some genes.
I have several files with sequences in order. I would like to extract first sequence of each file into new file and like till the last sequence. I know only how to do with first or any specific line with `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print; nextfile}' *.txt > newfile
```

Here I have input like this

File 1

```
Saureus081.1
ATCGGCCCTTAA
Saureus081.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTATA
Saureus081.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGG
```

File 2

```
SaureusRF1.1
ATCGGCCCTTAC
SauruesRF1.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTAGG
SaureusRF1.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGC
```

File 3

```
SaureusN305.1
ATCGGCCCTTACT
SauruesN305.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTAGA
SaureusN305.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAATG
```

And similar files 12 are there
File 4 
.
.
.
.File 12

Required Output
Newfile

```
Saureus081.1
ATCGGCCCTTAA
SaureusRF1.1
ATCGGCCCTTAC
SaureusN305.1
ATCGGCCCTTACT
Saureus081.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTATA
SaureusRF1.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTAGG
SauruesN305.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTAGA
Saureus081.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGG
SaureusRF1.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGC
SaureusN305.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAATG
```

I guess this task can be done easily with `awk` but not getting any idea how to do for multiple lines

Comment: I am sorry for posting wrong input data earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the modified question, the answer shall be done with some changes.

```
$ awk -F'.' 'NR%2{k=$2;v=$0;getline;a[k]=a[k]?a[k] RS v RS $0:v RS $0} END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file1 file2 file3
Saureus081.1
ATCGGCCCTTAA
SaureusRF1.1
ATCGGCCCTTAC
SaureusN305.1
ATCGGCCCTTACT 
Saureus081.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTATA
SauruesRF1.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTAGG
SauruesN305.2
ATGCCTTAAGCTAGA 
Saureus081.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGG
SaureusRF1.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGC
SaureusN305.3
ATCCTAAAGGTAATG
```

Brief explanation,

- Set `'.'` as the delimeter
- For every odd record, distinguish `k=$2` as the key of array `a`
- Invoke `getline` to set `$0` of next record as the value corresponds to the key `k`
- Print the whole array for the last step

Comment: Sorry not giving correct output when I do with my huge data

Comment: It worked for the case you post, if you adopt the same format of input for your huge data, it should be without problems.

Comment: It is giving odd output with my data here. Not in order

Comment: @ThulasiR, see my modified answer for your updated question

Answer (score 0):

***paste*** + ***awk*** solution:

```
paste File1 File2 | awk '{ p=$2;$2="" }NR%2{ k=p; print }!(NR%2){ v=p; print $1 RS k RS v }'
```

- `paste File1 File2` - merge corresponding lines of files
- `p=$2;$2=""` - capture the value of the 2nd field which is the respective key/value from `File2`

---

The output:

```
Seq1 
ATCGGCCCTTAA
Seq1
ATCGGCCCTTAC
Seq2 
ATGCCTTAAGCTATA
Seq2
ATGCCTTAAGCTAGG
Seq3 
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGG
Seq3
ATCCTAAAGGTAAGC
```

---

Additional approach for multiple files:

```
paste Files[0-9]* | awk 'NR%2{ k=$1; n=NF; print k }
      !(NR%2){ print $1; for(i=2;i<=n;i++) print k RS $i }'
```

Comment: Thank you..It worked fine with two files well but unfortunately I have 12  files. Sorry I didn't mention that in question earlier but now I edited

Comment: Actually this is working really well but the problem is with my input. In real my data does not contain seq1,seq 2 but it contains unique code for each sequence for simple understanding I wrote like that in question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ThulasiR, avoid confusing and post the actual frament

Comment: Sorry I'll immediately edit the post..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your data is very large, I would suggest creating temporary files:

```
awk 'FNR%2==1 { filename = $1 }
              { print $0 >> filename }' file1 ... filen
```

Afterwards, you can `cat` them together:

```
cat Seq1 ... Seqn > result
```

This has the additional advantage that it will work if not all sequences are present in all files.